# Automatically generate an employee number in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to programatically auto generate a sequential employee number based on the last employee number. Here is what I have in the Model, Controller and View and it doesn't display anything.

The generation of the employee number should happen when the initial create page is being loaded.

Please let me know how to fix this as I'm not getting any errors.

Model

```
  public function getNextEmployeeNumber()
    {

    $lastEmployee = Employee::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();

    if ( ! $lastEmployee )

        $number = 0;
    else
        $number = substr($lastEmployee->order_id, 3);

    return 'EMP' . sprintf('%06d', intval($number) + 1);
}
```

Controller

```
public function create()
{
    if (! Gate::allows('employee_create')) {
        return abort(401);
    }
    $employee_number = new Employee();
    $employee_number->getNextEmployeeNumber();

    $services = \App\Service::get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.app_please_select'), '');
    $cities = \App\City::get()->pluck('city', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.app_please_select'), '');
    $states = \App\State::get()->pluck('state', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.app_please_select'), '');
    $created_bies = \App\User::get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.app_please_select'), '');
    $emergency_contacts = \App\EmergencyContact::get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.app_please_select'), '');

    return view('admin.employees.create', compact('services', 'cities', 'states', 'created_bies', 'emergency_contacts', 'employee_number' ));
}
```

View

```
@section('content')
<h3 class="page-title">@lang('global.employee.title')</h3>
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['admin.employees.store']]) !!}

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        @lang('global.app_create')
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                {!! Form::label('first_name', trans('global.employee.fields.first-name').'*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::text('first_name', old('first_name'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'required' => '']) !!}
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                @if($errors->has('first_name'))
                    <p class="help-block">
                        {{ $errors->first('first_name') }}
                    </p>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                {!! Form::label('middle_name', trans('global.employee.fields.middle-name').'', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::text('middle_name', old('middle_name'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) !!}
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                @if($errors->has('middle_name'))
                    <p class="help-block">
                        {{ $errors->first('middle_name') }}
                    </p>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                {!! Form::label('last_name', trans('global.employee.fields.last-name').'*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::text('last_name', old('last_name'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'required' => '']) !!}
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                @if($errors->has('last_name'))
                    <p class="help-block">
                        {{ $errors->first('last_name') }}
                    </p>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
                {!! Form::label('employee_number', trans('global.employee.fields.employee-number').'*', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
                {!! Form::number('employee_number', old('employee_number'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '', 'required' => '']) !!}
                <p class="help-block"></p>
                @if($errors->has('employee_number'))
                    <p class="help-block">
                        {{ $errors->first('employee_number') }}
                    </p>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: What database are you using, and is there a reason you can't use an auto-incremented id column?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably creating it correctly in the `create()` method here:

```
$employee_number = new Employee();
$employee_number->getNextEmployeeNumber();
```

So `$employee_number` at this point likely has a correct value in the method.

You then pass this into the view as the variable `$employee_number` in the same `create()` method here:

```
return view('admin.employees.create', compact('services', 'cities', 'states', 'created_bies', 'emergency_contacts', '**employee_number**' ));
```

However, I can't see anywhere where you are referring to the *variable* `$employee_number` in the blade view outside the trans. If you use the var instead, this will give you an idea of perhaps what's going on.  IE I see you look to a previous form value, and I see you look at an error bag, but I don't see where you have called the variable in your view.  This would negate showing the value.  So - you likely have the process correct, I think you just forgot to add a call to the variable.  Remember, you don't actually have an employee created yet, you have a new object, but as far as I can see, just the employee_number field is attached to it at this point.

Comment: thank you so much, how would I call it in the view so it displays it on load?

Comment: In your view, add `{{$employee_number}}` where you want it displayed.  This should do what you need, as you have already correctly passed it to the view.

Comment: Odd.  It should.  You'll need to do some dd() early in the blade file, and then even in the controller to see what is in the `$employee_number` variable.  It may be null, or it may be a problem in transfer.  Dump the variable at various stages to see where its failing, as the display method above should provide a value shown on the blade view.